# How can I get Flutter version from code?

Tags: flutter

How can I get Flutter version from code?

I want to include the Flutter version in API UserAgent and logs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you need a custom build script that creates a file like

```
lib/src/flutter_version.dart
```

with content like

```
const String version = const <String,String>
{
  "channel": "alpha",
  "repositoryUrl": "https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git",
  "frameworkRevision": "d36e2f6191793de66e0a132ad8c86885829bc6b2",
  "frameworkCommitDate": "2017-06-21 15:09:10 -0700",
  "engineRevision": "b0dee695ecb9ea2438f4d74afdca45839858c311",
  "dartSdkVersion": "1.24.0-dev.6.7"
};
```

which you can create by

```
echo "const String version = const \<String,String\>" > lib/src/flutter_version.dart
flutter --version --machine >> lib/src/flutter_version.dart
echo ";" >> lib/src/flutter_version.dart
```

You can then just import it and read the value

```
import 'package:my_package/src/flutter_version';

main() {
  print(version['frameworkRevision']);
}
```

For other device information there is also https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/device_info

Comment: After 3 years, is there any directly function that can query flutter version form code?

Comment: Perhaps https://pub.dev/packages/package_info provides the info you want (haven't checked in a while what exactly it provides).

Comment: That is "App Version", not Flutter version.